# VB.Net - How to create IF statement to check for leap years?

Tags: vb.net

I want to try and tabulate days in a month into GridView and I came across this code. Note that its originally in C#, but I'm working with VB.net so I had to translate it:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Preventive_Dates
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Private ConnStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLIOTConnectionString").ConnectionString
  Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnStr)
  
  Class [myClass]
    Private _date As String
    Private _dayOfWeek As String

    Public Property dateList As String
        Get
            Return _date
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _date = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property dayOfWeek As String
        Get
            Return _dayOfWeek
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _dayOfWeek = value
        End Set
    End Property
  End Class

  Sub load_Calander()

    Dim year As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text)
    Dim month As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text)
    Dim myList As List(Of [myClass]) = New List(Of [myClass])()

    If month = 1 OrElse month = 3 OrElse month = 5 OrElse month = 7 OrElse month = 8 OrElse month = 10 OrElse month = 12 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To 31

            Dim item As [myClass] = New [myClass]()
            item.dateList = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", i.ToString(), Mth_Num.Text, CurrentYear.Text)
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = New DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentYear.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Mth_Num.Text), i)
            item.dayOfWeek = dateValue.ToString("ddddddddd")
            myList.Add(item)

        Next
    Else

      ElseIf month = 4 OrElse month = 6 OrElse month = 9 OrElse month = 11 Then

        For i As Integer = 1 To 30

            '*repeat code above for 1 to 31*

        Next

    Else

        For i As Integer = 1 To 28

            '*repeat code above for 1 to 31*

        Next

    End If

    GridView1.DataSource = myList
    GridView1.DataBind()


  End Sub
```

I'm glad it works out great, but I'm also thinking about how to do the same if there's a leap year. If I can  add an `ElseIf` to check every 4 years after 2024, like:

```
ElseIf year = 2024 'insert statement to help check every 4 years after

    For i as Integer = 1 to 29
       
        '*repeat code above for 1 to 31*

    Next
```

Question is that I have no idea how to create an `If` statement that specific. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net, `DateTime` has a built-in static function to check for leap years, `IsLeapYear`:

```
If (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)) Then
    ' Is a leap year
    ...
Else
    ' Is not a leap year
    ...
End If
```

The docs for this are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear) and state:

> Returns an indication whether the specified year is a leap year.

It is typically best practice to use inherent components to perform these kinds of checks rather than writing custom logic
to do it.  With leap years specifically, there is a set of rules that are adjusted dependent upon the following:

> [Leap years] occur in each year which is an integer multiple of 4
> (except for years evenly divisible by 100, which are not leap years
> unless evenly divisible by 400).

Better to use a built-in function than implementing a custom one (unless there is a valid reason for doing so, which of course there can be).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this code a lot by using the [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth) function:

```
Dim days As Integer
days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
For i As Integer = 1 to days
    '  code for each day in month
End For
```

No need to implement the logic for checking the days in a month yourself (including leap years)